# Highlight dates in jQuery UI calendar with range selector

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I need an inline jQuery UI calendar with a date range selector and highlighted / disabled dates.

My code example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/pgns4syL/1/)

This is a range selector, but all dates are normal. I need to colour into red the current date, for example, if it is *16/03/2018*, and colour into green all the others.

In a normal jQuery calendar whiteout the range selector:

```
beforeShowDay: function (date) {
var ddmmyy = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', date)
if ($.inArray(ddmmyy, dates) >= 0) return [false, 'gior-occ', " "];
return [true];
}
```

But in my jsfiddle you can see that I already have a `beforeShowDay` option selected.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question if you want the dates in your `dates` Array to always be unselectable & have a red border, or only after an initial selection is made. Based on the description though & sample code, I'll assume the former.

You can achieve the desired result by (1) moving the `dates` array down into your `beforeShowDay` initialization function and (2) cleaning up said function to the below:

```
function dateRange(date){
   var dates = ['16/03/2018'];
   var ddmmyy = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', date)
     if ($.inArray(ddmmyy, dates) >= 0) {
    return [false, 'gior-occ', " "];
   }

   var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate("MM d, yy", $("#checkinDate").text());
   var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate("MM d, yy", $("#checkoutDate").text());
   var isHighlight = date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2));

   return [true, isHighlight ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
}
```

That, combined with a small fix to your CSS (your `gior-occ` rule in your CSS had no leading period `.` so it was being applied as an element rule, not a class rule) ensures now that the `gior-occ` **class** rule is applied to dates that appear in the `dates` Array.

The forked & updated JSFiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/upmf7f8y/7/